# Can list interpolation be made listable?

Tags: interpolation

I have 8 sets of 2D-data that I want to each interpolate with `ListInterpolate`, because it is a very efficient command. The complete data are therefore in a 3D table. I would like to use `ListInterpolate` such that it returns a 2D function that evaluated to a 1D list (of 8 elements). How can I do that best? This would be using `ListInterpolate` in a listable way/ giving a list of 2D tables to it.

Comment: Look up `Map` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Sektor, this is indeed also here the good solution.

Comment: *Mathematica* permits adding the attribute `Listable` to `ListInterpolation`, but you don't want to do that -- it breaks the function.

Comment: Look up `ListInterpolation` in the documentation. There is no built-in function named `ListInterpolate`

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data in an array 'data' you can simply run `ListInterpolation` on each entry of the array via `Map` or `/@`

```
lip = ListInterpolation /@ data
```

or if you have to supply additional arguments

```
lip = ListInterpolation[#, whatever option or argument] & /@ data
```